# Is it possible to have 2 different passwords saved for the same network?

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, profile

I'm not always at home and sometimes the router needs to be reset completely to receive a new wan ip address because my roommates are not very tech savvy at all.  When this happens the password is reset to the default and I am unable to change this.  They do not know how to change this because they do not know how.  I have a raspberry pi running all the time with raspbian and need to have this connected to the network.  Unfortunately when they reset the router the raspberry pi has the old network profile saved and cannot authenticate with the router.  Is there a way to have two different profiles saved with different passwords for the same network?

EDIT
After being gone for a couple of days they already have it setup to use the default password so it looks like they want to keep it there.  Thank you for the help though.

Comment: What about changing the router's SSID along with the password?  That way, when it's reset to the default password the SSID should also be reset.  Then you simply need to configure two different networks.  Alternately, connect the Pi via cable instead of Wi-Fi so it doesn't need a password.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do a factory reset just to pick up a new IP address.  Can't you teach them to pull the power plug for 10 seconds and plug it back in?  Or get one of the extension cords made for Christmas trees with a remote switch.

Comment: We tried just unplugging it but it did not work.  The only way to fix it that we have tried is to reset it.  After searching the router configs there is a way to release the WAN lease but have not tried that.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know it is possible to add networks with the same essid. Do that twice with different passwords or use a power lan connection. Both should work.